# Passing Arrays from ios main application to WatchKit extension

Tags: ios, watchkit

I have this test WatchKit extension project which calls WKInterfaceController openParentApplication: in order to get the information to display
the main ios App then queries a database for the data to be sent back to the watch like this.

```
if ([userInfo objectForKey:@"categoryRequest"])
{   
    BFLiteDatabase * db = [BFDatabase getDatabase];
    NSMutableArray * categories = [NSMutableArray new];
    BFLiteCommand * cmd =  [db commandFromString:[BFCategory selectStatement]];
    while([cmd readNext])
    {
        [categories addObject: [[BFShoppingCategory alloc] initFromCommand:cmd]];
    }

    NSDictionary * result = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSArray arrayWithArray:categories] forKey:@"categoryResult"]];
    reply(result);    
}
```

But I get a sigbat as soon as I all reply and I have narrowed it down to the fact that i am assigning an nsarray to the value of a dictionary value.

I cant understand why this is illegal and what is the best workaround ?

Regards Christian Andersen

Comment: ok I  have found problem I think the issue is that the categories array contains BFShoppingCategory objects which i don't think are serilizeble  so instead of using objects i will just pass basic arrays and that should work

Answer (score 1):

I can't spot anything overtly wrong other than the fact that you're putting in way too much work just to create that final `NSDictionary`.

This would be a much cleaner way of approaching it:

`NSDictionary *result = @{@"categoryResult":[NSArray arrayWithArray:categories]};`

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014957-CH1-SW70)

> The contents of the dictionary must be serializable to a property list
>   file

This means `NSCoding` won't work. You can use the `RawRepresentable` protocol and recreate the object from the raw values.

Answer (score 0):

ok I have found problem I think the issue is that the categories array contains BFShoppingCategory objects which i don't think are serilizeble so instead of using objects i will just pass basic arrays and that should work